# Complex Analysis Polar Representation Questions

Tags: complex-analysis

My text (Gamelin's Complex Analysis) talks about the polar representation of a complex number.

At one point the equation $z^n = w$ is given.The polar representation $w = \rho e^{i \phi}$ is then given.  It says the equation $z^n = w$ becomes $r^ne^{in \theta} = \rho e^{i \phi}$.  It then says "Thus $r^n = \rho$ and $n\theta = \phi + 2\pi k$ for some integer $k$. This leads to the explicit solutions $r = \rho^{1/n}$, $\theta = \frac{\phi}{n} + \frac{2\pi k}{n}$."  I can understand where things like $r^n = \rho$ came from, but the rest completely confuse me.  Can someone help me understand this?

Thanks!

Comment: You might want to check your equation $r^ne^{in \phi} = \rho e^{i \phi}$; mayhaps it should read  $r^ne^{in \theta} = \rho e^{i \phi}$; i.e., $z = re^{i\theta}$.

Comment: Ah, thank you for noticing that.

Comment: Glad to help out!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean $z=re^{i\boxed{\theta}}$, then $r^ne^{in\theta}=\rho e^{i\phi}$. See that $e^{i\phi}=e^{i(\phi+2\pi k)}\forall k\in\mathbb{Z}$. Hence, $r^n=\rho$, and $n\theta=\phi+2\pi k\forall k\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: I do not understand how $z = re^{i \theta}$.  I understand I misquoted $\phi$ instead of $\theta$, but the rest of it confuses me since we were given $z^n = w$ and not $z = w$.

Comment: @Ethan $z=re^{i\theta}$ is a general definition of a complex number with argument $\theta$.

Comment: @Ethan $z^n=r^ne^{in\theta}=w=\rho e^{i\phi}$.

Comment: Where does $r^ne^{in \theta}$ come from, as opposed to just $re^{in \theta}$?

Comment: @Ethan Where is $r^ne^{i\theta}$ written?

Comment: $z^n = r^ne^{in\theta}$.

Comment: @Ethan Distribute: $(ab)^n=a^nb^n$.

Comment: Oh! Silly me!  Thank you for your help!

Comment: @Ethan Sure!${}{}{}$

Comment: Actually, one more question.  Is $r$ a complex number or a real number?

Comment: @Ethan A real number.

Comment: Sorry, I lied.  Last question:  How is solving for $r$ and $\theta$ the solutions?  Are they the roots?  If not what are they?  Thanks!

Comment: @Ethan The solution of the equation $z^n=w$ is given by solving for $r,\theta$. The meaning of solution here is similar to that you usually learn about in high school.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14225/discussion-between-ethan-and-sanath-devalapurkar)

Answer (score 1):

If a complex number is of the form $a\cdot e^{ib}$ with $a,b$ real, then $a$ is its length (distance from zero) and $b$ is its angle (measured from the right wing of $x$-axis, towards the $y$-axis).

So, if $r^n\,e^{in\theta}=\rho\,e^{i\phi}$ and $r,\rho,\theta,\phi$ are real, then, regarding the length and the angle of this complex number we must have the written equations ($r^n=\rho$ and $n\theta=\phi+2k\pi$ for some integer $k$).

And, since these are already real numbers, $r$ must be $\sqrt[n]\rho$ and $\theta=\displaystyle\frac\phi n+\frac{2k\pi}n$, which gives $n$ different solutions, for $k=0,\dots,n-1$ (and $k=n$ gives the same complex number as $k=0$).

Comment: Ah okay, I understand that much now, thank you!  Now I am just confused on the question I am asking Sanath Devalapurkar in the comments.